# How to detect if Delphi program runs in PlayOnMac

Tags: delphi, wine, delphi-xe7

I have a Delphi application which runs smooth in PlayOnMac under MacOS 10.9.5 Yosemite.

It has the feature to minimize the application to TrayBar. Since Mac is not having the concept of TrayBar I would like to disable this feature if the app runs on Mac.

Checking the Windows version is not an option since PlayOnMac really well obfuscates the fact that the host OS is Mac by emulating the Windows APIs and reporting that the OS is Windows XP for example.

How I can detect that the application is running in PlayOnMac?

Comment: What happens if your app tries to minimize to the "tray"? Does it fail? Does it simply hide with no way to restore it?

Comment: Have you asked the creators of the PlayOnMac or looked in their documentation? And how about all the other emulators out there? Do you want to support all those ones too?

Comment: BTW Yosemite is OSX 10.10 and OSX 10.9 is Mavericks

Comment: If the TrayBar is not supported, I would expect the API calls to behave slightly differently. E.g. `Shell_NotifyIcon` might always return False. Then you need only check the function result to know if you successfully added a Tray Icon and can hide your form. This has a couple of advatanges: Instead of disabling features globally based on the environment, you're doing so based on if the feature is supported. So a later version of PlayOnMac might support a TrayBar, and your app will be able to use them. Or if a Windows policy is set to disable the TrayBar, your app will behave accordingly.

Comment: It would help also if some standard terms were used. Windows doesn't have a TrayBar. Do you mean the notification area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [PlayOnmac engine uses Wine](http://www.playonmac.com/en/dev-documentation-5.html), you can try searching for the `wine_get_version` and `wine_nt_to_unix_file_name` methods on the *ntdll.dll* module using the  `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions.

Additionally try these resources.

- [How to detect if your Windows application is running under Wine](http://codejuggle.dj/how-to-detect-if-your-windows-application-is-running-under-wine/)
- [Detecting a virtualized environment](http://ruminatedrumblings.blogspot.com/2008/04/detecting-virtualized-environment.html)
- [uDGVMUtils](http://www.delphigeist.com/2011/01/udgvmutils-version-11-thanks-to-chee.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your app is running within an emulation system.  It thinks it is running on Windows, it does not see MacOS at all.  So unless PlayOnMac's emulation is reporting itself somehow in its emulation of `GetSystemInfo()` or the Registry, or somewhere else that a Windows app can access, then the app simply has no clue.  That is what emulation is all about.

Comment: That an emulator may perfectly emulate its target does not preclude it offering additional functionality to identify it.

Comment: @David Isn't that what Remy is saying? "_Unless_ (the emulator) is reporting itself (in a way) that a Windows app can acsess, ..."

Comment: @Craig I suppose so. But that just begs the question, the very question that the user asked and that RRUZ answered.